# jQuery not selecting list item

Tags: jquery, html

I'm reading a cookie to select a list item on page load (the cookie IS coming back--just to make sure, I hard-coded it and the select still didn't work). Nothing gets selected. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<select id="Carriers" size="20">
            <option value="0">Anaheim</option>
            <option value="0">CCMSI</option>
            <option value="0">City of Newport Beach</option>
            <option value="0">City of Santa Ana</option>
            <option value="0">Guard</option>
            <option value="1">Staffmark</option>
    </select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var cookie = getCookie(CookieName);
        if (cookie != null) {
            $("#Carriers").val(cookie);
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** It doesn't work in IE8 or in Chrome.

Comment: wheres your getCookie function?  how is your CookieName defined or is this just an example showing that's where you pass in the cookie name?

Comment: What browser/ version of jQuery? If IE7 or before and certain versions of jQuery will not work for .val() on select lists. Use .attr('value', val); instead and you should be fine.

Comment: Why do most of your options have the same value?

Comment: Setting val when all your vals are 0 or 1 is probably the cause...make the values unique.

Comment: Again, the cookie is not relevant. Even if I hard-code the value, it won't get selected in the list box. I'm using jQuery 1.9.0.

Comment: Have you tried what Pat is suggesting?

Comment: just to be sure... are your cookie values the option values (ie. the numbers), or the captions (carrier names)?

Comment: @Michael_B That did the trick. So there's no way to store a "boolean" as part of an HTML listbox? Please give your answer "officially" and I'll vote is as the answer.

Comment: You can do boolean, but you better only have two items in your select...one for 0 and one for 1.  Now..if you were trying to do multiselect..that's another story.

Comment: I'm just trying to store a bool for each option. I'll just hit the database with the name to retrieve that value I guess.

Comment: That's not really a best practice...but you can add 'multiple' to the select and have this output. http://jsfiddle.net/QdHB9/1/  I'd use the unique key in the database as the 'value'

Comment: How about assigning some arbitrary value to your tags and then check for that when retrieving the Boolean value? (<option value="something" bool="1">) I know it'll cause it to fail on W3C validation, if you're not using HTML5 document, but it should still work the way you want it to, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use unique values...

http://jsfiddle.net/QdHB9/

```
<select id="Carriers" size="20">
    <option value="0">Anaheim</option>
    <option value="1">CCMSI</option>
    <option value="2">City of Newport Beach</option>
    <option value="3">City of Santa Ana</option>
    <option value="4">Guard</option>
    <option value="5">Staffmark</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var cookie = 2;
    if (cookie != null) {
        $("#Carriers").val(cookie);
    }
});
```